# Image upload & gallery

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-6, gallery, cck

Is there a way to limit the number of imagefield fields present in a node?
I am using [iTweak Upload](http://drupal.org/project/itweak_upload), which allows to upload an unlimited number of images, but I need something that can limit the number of uploads.

I want to make a gallery per node with the uploaded files; what module do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) module + [filefield](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) module

Comment: is there a tutorial how to theme it? cause i dont like the sort option and some other stuff like the text "you can upload max 2mb size " ... etc

Comment: filefield_widget.inc contains all theme_ functions. You can override it in template.php using phptemplate_ instead theme_ in func name